# OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy 1.0, Flask 0.10, SQLAlchemy 0.8.2, and Python 2.7.5.  I'm connecting to MySQL 5.6 with Oracle's MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.12.

When I restart my web server (either Apache2 or Flask's built-in), I receive the exception `OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available` after MySQL's `wait_timeout` expires (default 8 hours).

I've found people with [similar problems](http://mofanim.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/sqlalchemy-mysql-has-gone-away/) and explicitly set `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 7200`, even though that's [Flask-SQLAlchemy's default](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L839).  When I put a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L826), I see that the teardown function is successfully calling `session.remove()` after each request.  Any ideas?

**Update 7/21/2014:**

Since this question continues to receive attention, I must add that I *did* try some of the proposals. Two of my attempts looked like the following:

**First:**

```
@contextmanager
def safe_commit():
    try:
        yield
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise
```

This allowed me to wrap my commit calls like so:

```
with safe_commit():
    model = Model(prop=value)
    db.session.add(model)
```

I am 99% certain that I did not miss any `db.session.commit` calls with this method and I still had problems.

**Second:**

```
def managed_session():
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                response = f(*args, **kwargs)
                db.session.commit()
                return response
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                db.session.close()
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

To further ensure I wasn't missing any commit calls, I made a Flask wrapper that enabled code such as (if I remember correctly):

```
@managed_session()
def hello(self):
    model = Model(prop=value)
    db.session.add(model)

    return render_template(...
```

Unfortunately, neither method worked. I also recall trying to issue SELECT(1) calls in an attempt to re-establish the connection, but I don't have that code anymore.

To me, the bottom line is MySQL/SQL Alchemy has issues. When I migrated to Postgres, I didn't have to worry about my commits. Everything just worked.

Comment: I ended up playing with the Recycle amount until it stopped happening. I will have to look up the exact amount but I believe it was about 3200.

Comment: You should also check your current MySQL configuration, you can query it to get the current recycling time. I had this issue as well and I fixed it by setting my timeout to 3600 if that helps you. Taking the real configured value still created problems so I just took half of it and have not have any issues since.

Comment: @javax: You changed MySQL's `wait_timeout` or SqlAlchemy's pool_recycle?  Either way, I just adjusted pool_recycle to 3600.  I'll check what happens tomorrow morning.

Comment: No dice.  Same error after 8 hours with pool_recycle set to 3600.

Comment: **Update**: I never could figure out a solution.  Instead, I used SQLAlchemy to migrate everything to PostgreSQL.  I haven't encountered a single problem since.

Answer (score 8):

I was having this problem and it was driving me nuts.  I tried playing with SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE but this didn't seem to fix the problem.

I finally found http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it , and adapted for flask-sqlalchemy.

After I started using the following pattern, I haven't seen the problem.  The key seems to be always assuring that a `commit()` or `rollback()` is executed.  So if there is if-then-else which doesn't flow through `commit()` (e.g., for detected error), also do `commit()` or `rollback()` before redirect, abort, render_template call.

```
class DoSomething(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        try:
            # do stuff
            db.session.commit()
            return flask.render_template('sometemplate.html')
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            raise
app.add_url_rule('/someurl',view_func=DoSomething.as_view('dosomething'),methods=['GET'])
```

**UPDATE 7/22/2014**

I discovered that I also had to change the SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE to be less than the MySQL interactive_timeout.  On the godaddy server, interactive_timeout was set to 60, so I set SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE to 50.  I think both the pattern I used, and this timeout were necessary to make the problem go away, but at this point I'm not positive.  However, I'm pretty sure that when SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE was greater than interactive_timeout, I was still getting the operational error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I did try this in the past w/o success (see my update).

Comment: Yes, I did see your migration to Postgres when I was investigating my problem, but I chose to stay with MySQL.  I haven't seen this problem since I have been using this pattern, while it happened quite frequently without.

I admit I haven't created my own decorators, and it looks like in the main line your solution would work as mine.  One question, though:

How does your solution cause commit or rollback through redirect or abort call?  Do you not have any of these in your code?

Comment: I don't have any redirects/aborts, but I don't see why they'd matter. They don't affect my first solution, and in my second, `response = f(*args, **kwargs)` would be set to redirect's response and an abort's exception would be caught and cause a rollback.

Comment: Ok.  Then I'm not sure why the solution seems to work for me, but didn't work for you.  I've been running for almost seven months with this pattern, without this failure.  Before using this pattern the problem would happen every day or other day.  I think I had to stay with MySQL because that the DBMS my web hosting service (godaddy) uses.  Maybe others who have the problem can try this and chime in.

Comment: Hmm, well it would be nice to have some closure on this issue. I'll try setting up a test environment in the next couple of days.

Comment: I figured I'd better double-check.  It turns out I also set SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE to 50 seconds around March 31, which if after I put the pattern I'd mentioned in (February).  It looks like I must have done the investigation into godaddy's MySQL server's timeout parameter (interactive_timeout) after discovering the referenced SQLAlchemy docs.  So, while I think the try-commit-except-rollback pattern is necessary, I  think it's not sufficient.  Apologies for the confusion I've wrought.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across the same issue recently - the first request to the MYSQL database after a long period of FLASK & SQLAlchemy application inactivity (at least 8 hours) results in an unhandled exception, which in turn implies *500 Internal Server Error: Connection Unavailable*. All subsequent requests are just fine.

I managed to boil down the problem to MYSQL connection by decreasing the *@@session.wait_timeout* (and *@@global* just in case) value to 5 seconds. Then every odd request was just alright, while every second after 5-plus-second pause failed. The conclusion was obvious - SQLAlchemy was using open, but timeouted on the database end connection.

## Solution

In my case it turned out the solution is spelled out in the [SQLAlchemy – MYSQL has gone away](https://mofanim.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/sqlalchemy-mysql-has-gone-away/) blog post:

> The first thing to make sure of is [...] the value of *pool_recycle* should be less than your MYSQLs *wait_timeout* value.

In MYSQL documentation you can find *wait_timeout* defaults to 8 hours (28 800 seconds), while SQLAlchemy engine's [*pool_recycle*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) default value is *-1*, that entails no connection recycle whatsoever. I simply passed the value of 21 600 (6 hours) to the *create_engine* function and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlalchemy` provides 2 ways of handling with disconnections, details in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects)

Short version:

- Optimistically

use `try...except` block to catch disconnection exceptions. This will return a `500` on the failing request, then the web application continues as normal. So use this one if disconnection happens infrequently. Note: you'll need to wrap each potential-to-fail operations in the `try...except` block.

- Pessimistically (the one I'm using)

Basically do an extra `ping` operation (something like `SELECT 1`) each time a connection is checked out from the pool. If the `ping` fails raise `DisconnectionError`, upon which the host pool will attempt to force a new connection to be created (in fact the pool will try 3 times before officially give up). In this way your application won't see `500` error. The tradeoff is the extra SQL executed, although according to the doc the overhead is small.

Comment: I don't think I've tried to raise a `DisconnectionError`. If I find some free time, I'll give this a go and update with my results. Thanks for your comment.